# ASP.Net Core sidecar logging in Kubernetes with Fluentd problem

Tags: asp.net-core, kubernetes, fluentd, sidecar

I have a K8s deployment that deploys an app's container (an ASP.Net Core application) along its sidecar for logging. I use Serilog's Console sink in order to log in the stdout. I also have a Config Map in order to store the fluentd's configuration. A very nice article about this part is [this](https://andrewlock.net/writing-logs-to-elasticsearch-with-fluentd-using-serilog-in-asp-net-core/).

What I'm trying to do is to use the sidecar to forward the logs from the app to Elastic Search. I use the respective output plugin in order to do that. But what should use in source and filter tags in order to achieve that?

The fluentd's configuration is the following:

```
      <source>
        @type forward
        port 24224
        bind 0.0.0.0
      </source>
        
      <filter *.**="">
        @type parser
        key_name log
        format json
        reserve_data true
      </filter>
        
      <match *.**="">
        @type copy
        <store>
        @type elasticsearch
        host 192.168.1.41
        port 9200
        logstash_format true
        logstash_prefix fluentd
        logstash_dateformat %Y%m%d
        include_tag_key true
        user elastic
        index_name "ap-*"
        password xxxxxxxxx
        type_name access_log
        tag_key @log_name
        flush_interval 1s
        </store>
        <store>
        @type stdout
        </store>
      </match>
```

Using this configuration, fluentd is working but I don't get any messages forwarded to Elastic Search.

Here are the logs of fluentd

```
2021-04-08 11:37:25 +0000 [info]: parsing config file is succeeded path="/fluentd/etc/fluent.conf"
2021-04-08 11:37:25 +0000 [info]: gem 'fluent-plugin-elasticsearch' version '5.0.2'
2021-04-08 11:37:25 +0000 [info]: gem 'fluentd' version '1.12.2'
2021-04-08 11:37:25 +0000 [info]: 'flush_interval' is configured at out side of <buffer>. 'flush_mode' is set to 'interval' to keep existing behaviour
2021-04-08 11:37:25 +0000 [info]: using configuration file: <ROOT>
  <source>
    @type forward
    port 24224
    bind "0.0.0.0"
  </source>
  <filter *.**="">
    @type parser
    key_name "log"
    format json
    reserve_data true
    <parse>
      @type json
    </parse>
  </filter>
  <match *.**="">
    @type copy
    <store>
      @type "elasticsearch"
      host "192.168.1.41"
      port 9200
      logstash_format true
      logstash_prefix "fluentd"
      logstash_dateformat "%Y%m%d"
      include_tag_key true
      user "elastic"
      index_name "catalogapi-*"
      password xxxxxx
      type_name "access_log"
      tag_key "@log_name"
      flush_interval 1s
      <buffer>
        flush_interval 1s
      </buffer>
    </store>
    <store>
      @type "stdout"
    </store>
  </match>
</ROOT>
2021-04-08 11:37:25 +0000 [info]: starting fluentd-1.12.2 pid=7 ruby="2.6.6"
2021-04-08 11:37:25 +0000 [info]: spawn command to main:  cmdline=["/usr/local/bin/ruby", "-Eascii-8bit:ascii-8bit", "/usr/local/bundle/bin/fluentd", "-c", "/fluentd/etc/fluent.conf", "-p", "/fluentd/plugins", "--under-supervisor"]
2021-04-08 11:37:26 +0000 [info]: adding filter pattern="*.**=\"\"" type="parser"
2021-04-08 11:37:26 +0000 [info]: adding match pattern="*.**=\"\"" type="copy"
2021-04-08 11:37:26 +0000 [info]: #0 'flush_interval' is configured at out side of <buffer>. 'flush_mode' is set to 'interval' to keep existing behaviour
2021-04-08 11:37:26 +0000 [warn]: #0 Detected ES 7.x: `_doc` will be used as the document `_type`.
2021-04-08 11:37:26 +0000 [info]: adding source type="forward"
2021-04-08 11:37:26 +0000 [info]: #0 starting fluentd worker pid=16 ppid=7 worker=0
2021-04-08 11:37:26 +0000 [info]: #0 listening port port=24224 bind="0.0.0.0"
```

I've made numerous attempts, with various configuration but nothing worked.

Thanks in advance for your time.

Comment: In order to find a working solution I added FileSink with serilog and used tail input plugin for fluentd. If anyone though comes across this and has another solution, please share :)